# How to filter an XML Document to a list of XPath expressions in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I have a dynamically loaded string list of simple XPath expressions that contain a 'whitelist' of all the valid nodes that my result document should contain. What us the best way in C# to filter the source document to a result document that contains only nodes that match my list of XPath expressions? My source document is currently loaded as an XDocument. Needs to have optimal performance, possibly processing many of these per second. Sounded simple to me at first, but I'm struggling to find the best (or any) way to do it given the array of choices for XML processing in .NET. This [XmlPathReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950778.aspx) from someone at Microsoft that combines an XmlReader with XPath matching seemed promising, but it hasn't been touched in eight years so not so sure.

Comment: I am not sure about the exact size of the files and the expected speed, but a plain XML reading (i.e., relying on XMLReader) is pretty quick. Going through all the nodes and checking whether the given node is/isn't part of the list (with a simple condition looking into the whitelist array) should deliver a pretty good performance in most of the cases.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Are you seeing significant performance issues with existing code?

Comment: Also consider LINQ to XML - the often forgotten bit of LINQ, but it's very neat